# Randomizing URL numbers in iMacros

Tags: web-scraping, imacros

I'm using iMacros because I want to scrape a certain site for ID's which are used in the URL, after which I want to press a button.

I know you can't use Regular Expressions or globbing in the syntax for URL GOTO.
But I figured there might be a way to enter variables into the URL GOTO=?
Preferable I wouldn't want to randomize the variable, but have it try every page from [1 - 99999]

This is what I currently have:

```
VERSION BUILD=8940826 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !VAR3 ("Math.floor(Math.random()*99999 + 1);")
URL GOTO=http://example.com/id/ "randomized_variable_here"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:press<SP>button
```

I have tried a few things, but I don't seem to be able to do this.
I have very little experience actually creating stuff for myself, I just modify scripts to fit my purposes, but should I look towards an HTML document or something like that to randomize that variable for me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple to get the string with a randomized variable:

```
' ...
SET !VAR3 EVAL("Math.floor(Math.random()*99999 + 1);")
URL GOTO=http://example.com/id/{{!VAR3}}
' ...
```

---

And the following code is for looping through [1 - 'Max:' value on the 'iMacros' sidebar]:

```
' ...
SET !LOOP 1
URL GOTO=http://example.com/id/{{!LOOP}}
' ...
```

Just play this macro in loop mode.